# How to run test in sequential order in loadimpact?

Tags: k6

We have 2 APIs which we wanted to test with load impact and the second API is the so-called dynamic target which is built upon the basis of data we get from the response of the first API.

Hence, We want to run this test sequentially. How can we achieve this?

```
import { check, sleep } from 'k6';
import http from 'k6/http';

    export default function() {
            let res, res_body, claim_url
            res = http.batch([req])
            check(res[0], {
                 "form data OK": function (res) {
                        console.log(res.status);
                        claim_url = JSON.parse(res.body)
                        console.log(claim_url.details.claim_uri)
                        return false;
                 }
    });
```

Does grouping of different APIs in a different function help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not limited to a single http request per default function iteration in any way. So you can just use whatever you want from the previous request and do a new one.

There is an example in the [http.post documentation](https://docs.k6.io/docs/post-url-body-params) but here is another simple one:

```
import { check, sleep } from 'k6';
import http from 'k6/http';

export default function() {
        let res, res_body, claim_url
        res = http.get(req);

        check(res, { // check that we actually didn't get error when getting the url
                  "response code was 200": (res) => res.status == 200,
             });
        claim_url = JSON.parse(res.body) // if the body is "http://example.org" for example
        res2 = http.get(claim_url); // use the returned url
        check(res2, { // here it's res2 not res
                  "response code was 200": (res) => res.status == 200,
             });
        // do more requests or checks

});
```

Comment: I was also thinking about this method but will the second function waits before first completed its execution?

Comment: Yes. k6 blocks on each line and waits for it to finish. There are no promises or async/await support at this point